# RESTful API - Control access to API (without a login page)

Tags: rest, oauth, spring-security, jersey, reverse-engineering

I have a RESTful webservice which communicates over HTTPS. I want to prevent other developers from calling the API. The API sits in front of a database which pulls data from a number of sources so i want to have control over who uses it. Using a login page is not an option

I've looked at Spring-security and OAuth however neither offers exactly what I need. I don't want to place a login page in front of the web service instead I just want to return a 400 or 401 http code when an unknown application attempts to call my service.

Can anyone recommend how i can implement this?

**Outcome** Thanks for feedback on this question. In the end i resorted to using an Apache module called mod_authz_host which allows you to restrict HTTP patterns to specific domains. While it is possible to spoof the domain this was for an internal app so the security requirement is more relaxed. I've includes a snippet below with details of how to use the Apache module

Include the following inside a Virtual host

```
<Location /yourProtectedServices/ws>
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from trusteddomain.com
</Location>
```

Comment: I'm curious how is opening up your API allowing someone to reverse engineer your application?

Comment: i'm trying to prevent other developers using the content exposed by these API calls. The Api sits in front of a database which pulls data from a number of sources and I would prefer to control who can get the data

Comment: ok I was thinking that but that's not reverse engineering your app. I'd rephrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your internal system you can create a list of Applications that have access with access tokens. Only developers/client apps with these authorised access tokens will then have access.  The catch on this is if the client app source code is viewable by others.

E.g. if someone created an Android Application with the access token in the code it could be reverse engineered when it is distributed in the app store.

Update:
For a more in depth view regarding security.
http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/

Comment: how is the access token passed between the client and the server, is it just an extra param hidden in a POST? Then on the server just pull the param from the request and return error code if not valid?

Comment: Yes and be sure to use https

Comment: the token would still be visible by someone viewing the Javascript source through the browser. How do you get around that?

Comment: Is all of the client app written in Javascript? If for example, someone was writing a web app that connected to your api it could use a public/private key method of sharing data. It would be important here thought that the private key is not exposed in the javascript.

Comment: my app is JavaScript. however there's nothing stopping someone calling the service from the server side. I could implement an interceptor to check the domain but again that would only handle requests from client side and could possibly be tampered with

Comment: Someone might prove me wrong but if the client code is viewable and you have no user authentication then you have no way of making this fully secure.

Comment: Thanks Derek. I experimented with mod_authz_host and spring handler interceptors whereby i check the domain making the web service request and block based on that. While by no means full proof it is enough for an internally facing application

Answer (score 0):

take this basic example:

server:

```
@Path("/your-path")
@RequestScoped
public class JSONService {

    private final static String  AUTH_TOKEN = "rxxkksdfnnchshs";        

    @GET
    @Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response fetchData(@QueryParam("auth_token") String auth_token) {

        if(AUTH_TOKEN.equals(auth_token)){

            final String results = "result: the object what you want";               

            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(results).build();  
        }
        else{

            return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();   
        }
    }
}
```

client:

```
@ManagedBean(name="your-bean-name")
@RequestScoped
public class ResteasyClient {
    private static final String BASE_URI    = "http://localhost:8080/your-context/your-rest-path";       
    private final static String  AUTH_TOKEN = "rxxkksdfnnchshs";
    ClientRequest webResource;
    ClientResponse response; 
    private String data;  

    public DBOResteasyClient() {           

        final String Path = "/your-path";
        webResource = new ClientRequest(BASE_URI+Path);            

    }

   @Produces
   @Named
    public String getData(){
        return this.data;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void fetchData() {

        try{
            ClientRequest resource = webResource;      
            response = resource.accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).queryParameter("auth_token",AUTH_TOKEN).get(ClientResponse.class); 
        }catch(Exception e ){
            //
        }

        if(response.getStatus() == 200 ){
            data = (String) response.getEntity(String.class);               
        }
    }  
}
```

this example use @QueryParam("auth_token") String auth_token in server to get a param of http request called auth_token and resource.accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).queryParameter("auth_token",AUTH_TOKEN) to add a param called auth_token, the key is: the server uses the param and compare it with own value "(AUTH_TOKEN.equals(auth_token)" and respond with http code how rest was built, http 200 if acept access "(Response.Status.OK)" http 401 if not "(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)"